# Pear Barcode 2 - save to disk

Tags: php, barcode, pear, gif, disk

I am generating a gif barcode using Pear Barcode2.

this currently works and I can see the image as gif image file. so the page is not shown in HTML form but as a stand alone image.

my code is:

```
$small_graph_height = 55;
        $small_graph_width = 1.2;
        $large_graph_height = 55;
        $large_graph_width = 1.14;
        $type = "gif";
        $code = "code39";
        $to_browser = TRUE;

          include_once "application/libraries/Image/Barcode2.php";

        $ticketno='TDN4993';
              $productserial_str = empty($productserial_str) ? ucfirst($ticketno) : $productserial_str;
              $productserial_type = $code;
              $productserial_imgtype = $type;
              $productserial_bSendToBrowser = $to_browser;
              $productserial_height = $large_graph_height;
              $productserial_width = $large_graph_width;

              $productserial_img = Image_Barcode2::draw($productserial_str, $productserial_type, $productserial_imgtype, $productserial_bSendToBrowser, $productserial_height, $productserial_width);

              ob_start();
                imagepng($productserial_img);
                $productserial_imgBase64 = base64_encode(ob_get_contents());
              ob_end_clean();

              imagedestroy($productserial_img);

               $image= '<img class="ProductSerial" src="data:image/' . $productserial_imgtype . ';base64,' . $productserial_imgBase64 . '">';
            echo $image;
```

what I want to do is save this image directly to the server hard disk  rather than display it to the user.

I have tried to use PHP's imagegif but it doesnt like the fact that $image is in a string format.

Any advice will be welcome. Thanks as always

Answer (score 1):

If you need to save the image on the disk you would need to use `imgpng()` function.

An example which i got from [here](http://grokbase.com/t/php/pear-general/11441n5f3a/image-barcode).

```
imagepng($bc->draw($data, $type, 'png', false),'ur_image_location');
```

Comment: Thanks, I did see this article but unsure how to modify the existing `$productserial_img = Image_Barcode2::draw($productserial_str, $productserial_type, $productserial_imgtype, $productserial_bSendToBrowser, $productserial_height, $productserial_width);` to your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$small_graph_height = 55;
$small_graph_width = 1.2;
$large_graph_height = 55;
$large_graph_width = 1.14;
$type = "gif";
$code = "code39";
$to_browser = TRUE;

include_once "application/libraries/Image/Barcode2.php";

$ticketno='TDN4993';
$productserial_str = empty($productserial_str) ? ucfirst($ticketno) : $productserial_str;
$productserial_type = $code;
$productserial_imgtype = $type;
$productserial_bSendToBrowser = $to_browser;
$productserial_height = $large_graph_height;
$productserial_width = $large_graph_width;

$productserial_img = Image_Barcode2::draw($productserial_str, $productserial_type, $productserial_imgtype, $productserial_bSendToBrowser, $productserial_height, $productserial_width);

ob_start();
imagepng($productserial_img);
$png = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

file_put_contents('barcode.png', $png);

echo 'image saved to file barcode.png';
```

Comment: Thanks asbb, the file is created correctly and the file displays correctly when the php page is called. problem is though that the image wont display from disk. on opening the image in notepad the error is: `<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  imagegif(): 56 is not a valid Image resource</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/capture.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 2873</p>

</div>`

Comment: Try to use imagepng instead imagegif.

Comment: sorry I did tru imagepng intially but the same error so tried imagegif. will post the imagepng error now.

Comment: `<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  imagepng(): 56 is not a valid Image resource</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/capture.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 2875</p>

</div>`